how to show all colours using ansii escape in batch
My batch script is working. I want it to echo words in a different color every second, and I'm using Ansii escape codes for the colors. In the end, I came up with this piece of code:
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
chcp 65001

REM Define ANSI escape codes
SET "ESC="

REM Set initial values for color variables
set /a col1=0
set /a col2=0
set /a col3=0

REM Loop through a range of iterations
for /L %%i in (1,1,25000) do (
    REM Print text with current color settings
    echo %ESC%[38;2;!col1!;!col2!;!col3!m"█▓▒▒░░░Text Editor░░░▒▒▓█"
    
    REM Pause
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
    
    REM Increment color variables
    if !col1! LSS 255 (
        set /a col1+=1
    ) else (
        if !col2! LSS 255 (
            set /a col2+=1
        ) else (
            if !col3! LSS 255 (
                set /a col3+=1
            ) else (
                echo No more color combinations
                pause
                exit /b
            )
        )
    )
)

This piece of code works, but changes the color from black->red->yellow->white
how do i show every color? and quickly?

the esc character (here=>  <=) was not recognized by stack overflow, but the %ESC% variable is set to the esc character. The error in the script wasn't because of that

Your code works fine, you're just starting with black text on a black background and it takes a few iterations to get to something visible. I'd recommend commenting out the timeout line.

Well, not fine since your logic brings red from 0 to 255 and then brings green from 0 to 255 and then brings blue from 0 to 255 so the whole output is just black->red->yellow->white, but my point is that the colors eventually change if you wait for a bit.

but how do you print every color and not just black->red->yellow->white?

Due to how RGB colors work, you're going to see a lot of colors that look identical to ones you've already seen. You're just going to have to take my word that they're different, albeit almost imperceptibly.
All you have to do is nest three for /L loops and then you don't have to keep track of any counters at all.
@echo off
setlocal


set "ESC="
for /L %%A in (0,1,255) do (
    for /L %%B in (0,1,255) do (
        for /L %%C in (0,1,255) do (
            echo %ESC%[38;2;%%A;%%B;%%Cm█▓▒▒░░░Text Editor░░░▒▒▓█
        )
    )
)

Like your code, this one also has an escape character in the set statement that gets swallowed by Stack Overflow.
